# Firewall service enabled /disabled via Powershell script

Tags: powershell-3.0

Being entry level, I'm trying to obtain a powershell script that can scan a OU Container named 'Servers', to see which servers have the windows firewall service enabled /disabled which is mpssvc.

Does anyone have a script I can run to see this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:
For searching the OU:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/9d501454-2f51-43b5-8bea-303a1c9f2094/

For retrieving Firewall state:
http://poshcode.org/836

Or, if you are on PowerShell v3:
http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/manage-windows-firewall-with-powershell-3/